# Selected Text color not saving

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SQL Server (SSMS 18.5.1), the selected text color is this light blue by default that is very hard to see. I found where to change it, but I've noticed that if I open a new tab, my new color selection doesn't migrate to the new tab, and I want to say in one instance, my previously open tab reverted to the old color. Is there a way to make this change permanent or the 'new' default?

Making change:

[image]

New tab and it has changed:

[image]

Comment: Furthermore, I can change the colors of everything else, like background color, color of operators, SP's, functions, etc. and those will stay. I pretty much went with a dark theme so that way I can at least see the Selected Text now because the Selected Text continues to revert to the Default (very light blue) everytime I open a new tab.

Comment: It not an answer but if you are only working with SQL Server it might be worth looking at Azure Data Studio. I use if for almost everything I do (which is mainly writing t-sql). There is a comparison chart here, but it's free so nothing to lose. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-ver15